# Why did twitter move from clientside rendering to serverside rendering?

Tags: javascript, templates, client-side

In [a blog post](http://engineering.twitter.com/2012/05/improving-performance-on-twittercom.html) Twitter states they have moved from clientside rendering back to serverside rendering.

I am trying to find a more thorough explanation of the reasons.

In the post they state:

> [clientside rendering] lacked support for various optimizations available only on the server.

What are the optimizations that are lacking clientside?

They also state:

> [serverside rendering] reduce[s] differences in performance across browsers

I read this as some browsers didn't perform well with clientside rendering.  Which browsers and how much slower was the rendering?

Comment: You might get better information if you contact them....

Comment: Pretty easy to tell which browser wasn't performing well. More than likely they had to do it because rendering DOM elements or doing pretty much any DOM manip's in IE just totally blows. Anytime you have to add elements to a page it is generally best to render them on the dom and just insert them all at once to the page.

Comment: As a follow-up to @scrappedcola I've tested the performance of DOM manipulation in IE (iirc 10000x append,remove). Chrome 20 needed ~0 ms, IE9 needed 16 secs (IE6: about a minute).

Comment: Also, I had meant "render them on the server and just insert them all at once on the page"

Answer (score 0):

I would speculate optimizations such as caching of various content chunks, as well as running as at a byte/op code level instead of being re-interpreted by the browser.  As far as clients go, its probably IE (especially pre-9) and maybe a few other older browsers.  Also possibly for various mobile devices where cpu is at a preimum and a little extra HTML coming down the wire is preferable to waiting until the cpu can get around to running all your javascript.

Of course it also means that the rendered html is a little more difficult to scrape, so it helps them to add a little bit of a road block for people wanting to write scripts to twiddle with the twitter web site look.